# LTS 6.7.3 - Issues Browsing -> right window with issues-list is empty, but data is delivered

Tags: sonarqube

> Sonarqube 6.7.3 - PostgreSQL 8.4.20 - jdk1.8.0_151 - OS OEL 6.5 (64bit)

I have upgraded from `5.6.7 (LTS)` to `6.7.3 (LTS)`. When I browse on the issues (either from main page "Issues" for from projects->select project->"Issues") and work with filters, then sometimes the issues-list on the right side is empty (even in the title there is displayed "1/x isses"). If I use firefox an go to the debug console, I can see that there are x issues delivered, but not displayed.

On small project I can see the issues without any problem. On projects with may issues (20k) the issues-list is missing.

When I go directly to "Issues" without selecting any projects an work on the filters, the issues-list (right side) is empty and on top you see the amount of issues without filtering. If I press on the reload-symbol left of the amount of issues, then the number is changed ... But no issues are displayed. If I look on the debug-monitor I can see the json-answere from the request and there are 100 issues (like in the paging-object described in pagesize and the total-object has the number of issues displayed in the top of the right side).
I think there must be somethink with the javascript processing of the result data.

I have testet with `firefox 47.0.1`, `52.x` and `IE11`.

**Any idea? Can I do some task to deliver more informations?**

Thanks for helping ...

Comment: Does Sonarqube have a support site? I'd think this would be far more on-topic there than it would be on SO, since it's not about your own programming, but rather a possible bug in someone else's.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint with the browser console (on Firefox: **shift-control-k**) from @Stas Vilchik. Now I can see an error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: e is undefined
```

and are able to deliver the error informations to the developers.